# Where ModifyVertices from BaseVertexEffect moved in BaseMeshEffect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble with my code that I'm adopting from now deprecated BaseVertexEffect, and to be honest I don't know where I made a mistake:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    [AddComponentMenu( "UI/Effects/Gradient" )]
    public class Gradient : BaseMeshEffect
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private Color32 topColor = Color.white;
        [SerializeField]
        private Color32 bottomColor = Color.black;

        public override void ModifyVertices(VertexHelper vh)
        {
            if(!this.IsActive())
                return;
            List<UIVertex> vertexList = new List<UIVertex> ();
            vh.GetUIVertexStream(vertexList);

            ModifyVertices (vertexList);

            vh.Clear ();
            vh.AddUIVertexTriangleStream(vertexList);

            int count = vertexList.Count;
            float bottomY = vertexList[0].position.y;
            float topY = vertexList[0].position.y;

            for( int i = 1; i < count; i++ )
            {
                float y = vertexList[i].position.y;
                if( y > topY )
                {
                    topY = y;
                }
                else if( y < bottomY )
                {
                    bottomY = y;
                }
            }

            float uiElementHeight = topY - bottomY;

            for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
            {
                UIVertex uiVertex = vertexList[i];
                uiVertex.color = Color32.Lerp( bottomColor, topColor, (                 uiVertex.position.y - bottomY ) / uiElementHeight );
                vertexList[i] = uiVertex;
            }
        }
    }
```

and error:

> error CS0115: `Gradient.ModifyVertices(UnityEngine.UI.VertexHelper)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override

can someone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the keyword override on `ModifyVertices`, you're attempting to override a method named `ModifyVertices` on the base class [BaseMeshEffect](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.BaseMeshEffect.html). Since there is no method named `ModifyVertices` to override, this error occurs.

The root of this appears to be that you intended to use [BaseVertexEffect](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.BaseVertexEffect.html) (which does have this method, but was removed as of Unity3D 5.3.3) and were directed to use BaseMeshEffect instead.

You'll need to properly override `ModifyMesh` by renaming your method to match, and then updating your existing code to get a VertexHelper (that you previously passed in on ModifyVertices) from the new input [Mesh](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html):

```
public override void ModifyMesh (Mesh mesh)
{
    List<UIVertex> vertexList = new List<UIVertex>();
    using (VertexHelper vertexHelper = new VertexHelper(mesh))
    {
        // Move previous VH-related code that you need to keep here
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @TomaszM please check my edit of the post to see if it aligns with your problem (I've made title way less generic and slightly aligned with this answer). Feel free to revert and update title to be nicer if it does not match your intention (make sure not to invalidate the answer so).